# I Send an ICMP Redirect packet to my IP address, but my IP routing table not change

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu, icmp

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/udp.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
void send_icmptime(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t len);
uint16_t in_cksum(uint16_t *addr, int len);
#define MAXLINE 1024
void main()
{   
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    struct addrinfo *ai;
    int on =1;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "186.9.9.9", &sin.sin_addr);
    if( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0)
        perror("socket");
    if( setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(int)) < 0)
        perror("setsockopt");
    send_icmptime(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
}
void send_icmptime(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *s, socklen_t len)
{


    struct in_addr myaddr;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.21.203.91", &myaddr);
    struct icmp *icmp;
    struct timeval val;
    struct ip *ip1;

    ip1 = (struct ip *)malloc(56);
    ip1->ip_v = 4;
    ip1->ip_hl = 5;
    ip1->ip_tos = 0;
    ip1->ip_len = 56;   
    ip1->ip_id = 0;
    ip1->ip_off = 0;
    ip1->ip_ttl = 64;
    ip1->ip_p = IPPROTO_ICMP;
    ip1->ip_sum = 0;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.21.203.91", &ip1->ip_src);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "61.135.169.125", &ip1->ip_dst);


    icmp = (struct icmp *)((char *)ip1 + 20);
    icmp->icmp_type = ICMP_REDIRECT;
    icmp->icmp_code = ICMP_REDIRECT_HOST;
    icmp->icmp_cksum = 0;
    icmp->icmp_gwaddr = myaddr;

    struct ip *ip;
    ip = (struct ip *)((char *)icmp + 8);
    ip->ip_v = 4;
    ip->ip_hl = 5;
    ip->ip_tos = 0;
    ip->ip_len = htons(55); 
    ip->ip_id = 0;
    ip->ip_off = 0;
    ip->ip_ttl = 54;
    ip->ip_p = IPPROTO_UDP;
    ip->ip_sum = 0;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.31.0.1", &ip->ip_src);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.21.202.91", &ip->ip_dst);
    ip->ip_sum = in_cksum((u_short *)ip, 20);

    struct udphdr *udp;
    udp = (struct udphdr*)((char *)ip + 20);
    udp->uh_sport =  6666;
    udp->uh_dport =  6666;  
    udp->uh_ulen = htons(55);
    udp->uh_sum = in_cksum((u_short *)udp, 8);
    icmp->icmp_cksum = in_cksum((u_short *)icmp, 36);
    if(sendto(sockfd, ip1, 56, 0 ,s, len) < 0)
        perror("sendto");
}
uint16_t in_cksum(uint16_t *addr, int len)
{
    int nleft = len; 
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    uint16_t *w = addr;
    uint16_t answer = 0;
    while(nleft > 1)
    {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
    }
    if(nleft == 1)
    {
        *(unsigned char *)(&answer) = *(unsigned char *)w;
        sum += answer;
    }
    sum = ( sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    answer =~sum;
    return answer;

}
```

root@zz-E431:/home/zz# tcpdump -i ppp0 icmp
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
    13:01:46.891807 IP 172.31.0.1 > 172.21.202.91: ICMP redirect 61.135.169.125 to host 172.21.203.91, length 36

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about your actual problem, but you do know that `lo` is not a normal interface and packets sent to it don't follow the normal rules?

Comment: but When I change lo address to my IP address 172.21.202.91 , my routing table not change too.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to configure your ICMP parameters. Have you changed any of the kernels default values for handling ICMP? As http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html states:

```
   ICMP_REDIRECT packets are not sent when Linux is not acting as a
   router.  They are also accepted only from the old gateway defined in
   the routing table and the redirect routes are expired after some
   time.
```

The ICMP settings can be changed under /proc Please read https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt especially for `accept_redirects` and `secure_redirects`. The latter by default prohibits redirects from anywhere but the gateways (in the routing tables).

Comment: I can send an ICMP REDIRECT packet to a host in subnet,and I changed IP source address to gateway address. The host can recieve the    packet I have send, but routing table not changed.

Comment: Hi @ZhangZhao: Is the code listed above sending icmp redirect packet to host in your subnet? Did you enable icmp redirects in your linux kernel file system under the file "proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects = 1". You can set accept_redirects to 1 for all files inside ipv4/conf/all folder and check

Answer (score 0):

Hi @ZhangZhao: Is the code listed above sending icmp redirect packet to host in your subnet? Did you enable icmp redirects in your linux kernel file system under the file "proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects = 1". You can set accept_redirects to 1 for all files inside ipv4/conf/all folder and check